# How to solve the problem of getting unusual id in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my routes

```
Route::get('add-members/{id}','MemberController@create');
Route::post('save-member/{id}','MemberController@store');
```

This is my code to show the create form

```
public function create($id)
    {
        $team=Team::find($id);
        $users = User::doesntHave('teams')->whereHas('roles', function($role) {
            $role->where('name', 'member');
        })->get();
        return view('members.create',compact('users','team'));
    }
```

An this is my code to store it

```
public function store(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $team=Team::find($id);
        dd($request->id);
        $team->users()->attach($request->id);
        return redirect('home');
```

}
and this is my blade file

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <form action="{{url('save-member',$team->id)}}" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Select Member/s') }}</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @foreach($users as $key => $user)
                    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->email}}<br>
                @endforeach
                @error('member_id')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong><font
                            color="red">{{ $message }}</font></strong></span>
                @enderror
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
@endsection
```

Now when i select none of the user and just click save button it will save the the user id as  1. After i am doing dd($request->id) it will show me the output 1. But in my form there is no users left or my form is empty.So where from 1 is coming. you can see this picture for clearify.
[image]
Please help me to solve this problems

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: as you can see my picture, this is a form for selecting user. And currently i have no users to select. So if i just click save then it will save as user id as 1 on my database.

Comment: Yeah but what is the question? You don't want it to work at all without users or what?

Comment: my question is "why this id saved as 1" as i have no user. Why when i doing dd() it will show me 1

Comment: Because you're passing `$team->id` on the URL .-.

Comment: but i am dd($request->id) not dd($id).

Comment: Edit the question and post your routes

Comment: because `$request->id` is going to return an 'input', if one isn't found it will return a route parameter and your route parameter for `id` is 1

Comment: then how i solve it, if nothing is requests then it will be redirect to home without saving to the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be more specific with what data you are requesting from the `Request`:

```
$request->id; // could be an input named 'id' or a route parameter named 'id'

$request->input('id'); // is an input
$request->route('id'); // is a route parameter
```

You are running into a situation where you have a route parameter named `id` and potentially an input named `id`. Using the dynamic property of the Request, `$request->id`, will return the input `id` if it is there, if not it falls back to returning a route parameter named `id`.

Here is an article from the past that shows the issue with not being specific about what you are trying to get from the `Request` object:
[asklagbox - blog - watch out for request](https://asklagbox.com/blog/illuminate-request)